# Check if any of the coordinates are within a certain distance using apply in Python pandas with two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this code that takes the vessel coordinates and checks them against every possible port coordinates. If the distance between the vessel and the port coordinates is within x meters (in this example, it has to be less than 3 km), then add that *port* and the *distance_to_the_port* to the data frame.

Example dataframes:

```
df_ports = pd.DataFrame({'Ports':['Port_A','Port_B','Port_C'], 'latitude': [1,5,3], 'longitude':[1,10,5]})
latitude_and_longitude_columns = df_ports.iloc[:, [1,2]]
df_ports['coordinates_tuple'] = latitude_and_longitude_columns.apply(tuple, axis=1)

df_vessel = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': [1,5,7], 'longitude':[1,10,20]})
latitude_and_longitude_columns = df_vessel.iloc[:, [0,1]]
df_vessel['coordinates_tuple'] = latitude_and_longitude_columns.apply(tuple, axis=1)

df_vessel['distance_to_port_in_meters'] = -1
df_vessel['port'] = -1
```

The function that checks the distance:

```
def get_distance_between_two_points(tuple1, tuple2):
    from geopy import distance    
    radius = 3000
    dist = distance.distance(tuple1, tuple2).m
    if dist < radius:
        return dist 
    return -1
```

The logic:

```
for _, port_row in df_ports.iterrows():

        port = port_row['Ports']
        result = df_vessel.apply(lambda vessel_row : get_distance_between_two_points(vessel_row['coordinates_tuple'], port_row['coordinates_tuple']), axis=1)

        for index, value in result[result != -1].items():
            df_vessel.loc[index, 'distance_to_port_in_meters'] = int(value)
            df_vessel.loc[index, 'port'] = port
```

Result:

```
 latitude  longitude coordinates_tuple  distance_to_port_in_meters    port
0         1          1            (1, 1)                           0  Port_A
1         5         10           (5, 10)                           0  Port_B
2         7         20           (7, 20)                          -1      -1
```

The result is correct and it works with my bigger data sample.

How can I improve this?

In my current code, I have 4800 vessel coordinates and 137 ports. It takes just above 2 minutes to go through the code. How can I make my code better and possibly faster?

Comment: _In my real code, I use a different one_ - so show your real code?

Comment: Based only on latitude and longitude, great-circle distance is a somewhat involved calculation. Are you calculating great circles?

Comment: I have edited the function. I have been reading that the last thing to do in pandas is to loop over a data frame. Is it possible to avoid the for loop in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop your use of `geopy`. So far as I can see it does not support vectorised inverse geodesics. Instead use `cartopy` which inherently supports this.

The following example code uses random instead of real data, but with the same size as your real data, and completes in about one second. `distances` and `close` are both matrices whose rows correspond to vessels and columns correspond to ports. `close` is a matrix of booleans for vessel-port pairs that are proximate.

```
import numpy as np
from cartopy.geodesic import Geodesic
from numpy.random import default_rng

N_VESSELS = 4_800
N_PORTS = 137

rand = default_rng(seed=0)

vessels = rand.random((N_VESSELS, 2)) + (1, -51)
ports = rand.random((N_PORTS, 2)) + (1, -51)
source = vessels.repeat(N_PORTS, axis=0)
dest = np.tile(ports, (N_VESSELS, 1))

geo = Geodesic()
distances = geo.inverse(source, dest).base[:, 0].reshape((N_VESSELS, N_PORTS))
close = distances < 3_000
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for teaching me this.